# Understanding JavaScript classes - resource class

Tags: javascript, class, html

Working on a simple video game in JavaScript / HTML5, and I had a thought to collect all of my resources within one class...currently they're spread all over the place.

So, for an example, currently I have something along the lines of

```
function c_enemy_sprites() {
  this.image = new Image();
  this.image.src = "res/enemies.png";
  ..
  ..
}

function c_tilemap() {
  this.image = new Image();
  this.image.src = "res/tilemap.png";
  ..
  ..
}
```

I'd like to commonize this into a single class, as so

```
function c_resource() {
  this.enemies.image = new Image();
  this.enemies.image.src = "res/enemies.png";

  this.tilemap.image = new Image();
  this.tilemap.image.src = "res/tilemap.png";
  ..
  ..
}
```

However, I don't think this is the proper approach.  The program crashes spectacularly when I try the second implementation.  Is there a good way to simplify my resource loading?

Comment: JavaScript isn't OOP so doesn't have the traditional class model. Functions are the first class citizens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating an object literal to hold everything:

```
function C_resource(src) {
    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.src = src;
}

var resources = {
    enemies : new C_resource('res/enemies.png'),
    tilemap : new C_resource('res/tilemap.png')
};

resources.enemies.image; // your enemies image.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing an object to put your image resource in:

```
function c_resource() {
  this.enemies = {};
  this.enemies.image = new Image();
  this.enemies.image.src = "res/enemies.png";
  this.tilemap = {};
  this.tilemap.image = new Image();
  this.tilemap.image.src = "res/tilemap.png";
  ..
}
```

You also could use:

```
function Resource(path){
   this.image = new Image();
   this.image.src = path;
   ... further initialization, etc.
}
```

then...

```
function resources(){
  this.enemies = new Resource('res/enemies.png');
  this.tilemap = new Resource('res/tilemap.png');
}
```