# Continuing JavaScript "classes" - enums within

Tags: javascript, class, html, enums, pseudo-class

From a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608204/understanding-javascript-classes-resource-class), I have the following:

So I have implemented a resource class, now I'd like to continue extending it and add all my constants and enums (or as far as JS will allow...).

This is what I currently have:

```
var resources = {
  // images
  player  : new c_resource("res/player.png"),
  enemies : new c_resource("res/enemies.png"),
  tilemap : new c_resource("res/tilemap.png")
};
```

And this is what I would like to continue to extend it to:

```
var resources = {
  // images
  player  : new c_resource("res/player.png"),
  enemies : new c_resource("res/enemies.png"),
  tilemap : new c_resource("res/tilemap.png"),

  // enums
  directions : {up:0, right:1, down:2, left:3},
  speeds     : {slow: 1, medium: 3, fast: 5}
};

...

function enemies() {
  this.dir = resources.directions.down; // initialize to down
}
```

When I attempt to access resources.directions.up, my JS script goes down in a flaming pile of burning code.  Are enums allowed in this context, and if not, how can I properly insert them to be used outside of a normal function?  I have also tried defining them as global to a similar effect.

---

edits: fixed the comma...that was just an error in transcribing it.

When I run it in Firefox and watch the console, I get an error that says `resources is undefined`.

The resources 'class' is defined at the top of my script, and `function enemies()` directly follows...so from what I understand it should still be in scope...

Comment: you're missing a comma after the tilemap line.

Comment: How are you using the enemies() function?

Comment: seems that i was initializing my enemies function before resources was declared...it works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the call stack to `enemies`? You could have done something like this:

```
var foo = {
  bar: 1,
  f_rv: f()
};

function f() {
  return foo.bar;
}
```

which works halfway since you can declare functions "below" the code that uses them, but fails later since `f()` attempts to use `foo`, which is not constructed at the moment.

Comment: In my case, using google closure, I was declaring the enum foo.Bar.MyEnum = { ... }; before my constructor foo.Bar. When I moved it to the other side of the constructor the issues cleared up.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a comma after `tilemap : new c_resource(...)` so `resources` is never properly assigned, so `resources.directions.up` fails because `resources` is undefined and undeclared.

Comment: Updated...it was simply an error in transcribing my code since I didn't directly copy it...I still have an error

Answer (score 2):

***It works:*** http://jsfiddle.net/XfurM/2/

In JavaScript, enums can be achieved by simply declaring an array or object, using the literal notation:

```
var weekdays = [
    'Monday',
    'Tuesday', 
    'Wednesday', 
    'Thursday', 
    'Friday', 
    'Saturday', 
    'Sunday'
];
```

or

```
var weekdays = {
    Monday: 1,
    Tuesday: 2,
    Wednesday: 3,
    Thursday: 4,
    Friday: 5,
    Saturday: 6,
    Sunday: 7
};
```